# Downloading file stopped working on Chrome but works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, adblock

I have an Angular application and user can download a file pressing a button. It worked perfectly fine, but recently stopped working in Google Chrome. The code hasn't been touched after creation.

component.pug file:

```html
button.btn.btn-default((click)="export()") Export
a([hidden]="true", target="_blank", download="export.csv", #exportButton) Real export
```

component.ts file export function:

```js
 export() {
    this.exportButton.nativeElement.href = this.gridExportService.getDataUrl(this.data, this.columns, this.valueType, this.selectedCurrency, this.separator, this.numberLocale);
    this.exportButton.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

Right now after clicking the download triggering button new tab opens with blob: link and then closes without the file being downloaded. The application works fine on Firefox.

Can't figure out what's causing this.
Thanks!

Comment: If it works in FireFox and not in Chrome anymore, clear cache in chrome, check what settings have changes on the browser you are testing. User might have changed settings or network admins have changed settings. It's most likely environmental and not much we can help you with aside from speculating. - Also your `getDataUrl` could be receiving a new format of the data now causing this. Have you debugged the received data? using `console.log()` and `debugger` in the Chrome console?

Comment: I updated my question with my code.

Comment: Yes, I have debugged and checked that getDataUrl returns the right format

Comment: Try running it in an incognito window in Chrome and see if you get the same result.

Comment: It worked in incognito window.. And also it's not a problem just in my computer, we got the feedback from application users.

Comment: Okay, that's progress anyway.  Try to narrow down the differences between normal and incognito - cache, extensions, cookies, localStorage etc..

Comment: Thank you! After disabling AdBlock it started working! Is there any other solution for it besides telling all the users to disable AdBlock?